# Want to change the search instead of just one option to a few

Tags: android

In code below you can only get an item if equals its COL_1 but what if I want more than one option like as well COL_2 and COL_3 ?

```
public Cursor getItem(String item_name ,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
            String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5};
            String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
            String [] selection_args = {item_name};
            return sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work as i never tried sql queries like that but try (String selection = COL_1 + "," + COL_2 + "," + COL_3 + " LIKE ?";)

Comment: the app crashed when I searched :(

Comment: as i said i never tried it that way but i assume thats where you need to add all the col's you want to search for -- what about (String selection = COL_1,COL_2,COL_3 + " LIKE ?";)

Comment: that just gives me an error ,I think I need to change something in a different class where it's calling this method